# Cljs Re-frame: what’s the recommended architecture for a game loop or timer?

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

Within the context of re-frame’s interceptor, coeffects / effects concepts I’m wondering what the recommended architectural approach is for events that are driven by a timer / cyclical event.

In one of the github examples a clock is made by defining a top level JavaScript interval at the namespace level (essentially a global).

In react this is the type of thing you would organize using component lifecycle hooks. What is a recommended way of organizing these types of event drivers (timers and request animation frame game loops)?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've found for an official answer is this: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/FAQs/PollADatabaseEvery60.md

Basically, it uses `(js/setInterval #(re-frame/dispatch event) frequency)` to dispatch an event on a timer. If you wrap it in a `swap!` that updates an atom you can keep track of it outside of the event handler (so you can cancel it).

That link includes a discussion of some nuances in setting up an infrastructure for cleaning up orphaned timers (e.g. because of a Figwheel hot reload). Call the initializer with `dispatch-sync` during your startup.